# How to remove faucet with no screw?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

**NEW EDIT #2, SEE BELOW:**

Kitchen sink drips from the tap, stops when I turn off hot water shut-off underneath, so I assume the problem is the hot water faucet. I think I know how to repair a faucet with a screw (unscrew to access cartridge and replace it), but when I pried the "H" cap off this one *and* the metal disk under the "H", there was no screw underneath...just a hole (see photos).

There appears to be nothing obvious inside to unscrew. So, **how do I proceed to fix this faucet?**

Thanks!

---

**EDIT #2**: I give up on removing it from above--I am going to try to remove this from underneath the sink. I'm attaching new photos of what that looks like, and asking for guidance. As you can see, this has been dripping down and rusted out the washer. Do I definitely need a basin wrench to do this, or can I use a socket wrench? What happens when I get this disconnected from underneath?

**Whole sink underneath, showing faulty hot water on right:**
[image: Whole sink underneath showing faulty hot water]

**Hot water underneath, close-up:**
[image: Hot water close-up]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. That hole looks like where the screw **used** to be. Perhaps the handle is held on by friction; have you tried (gently) prying and tapping to get it off?

Comment: @DanielGriscom No, I haven't tried that. I've tried turning the "bell" shape at the bottom while holding the T steady, but it was challenging, and didn't feel like it feels when you unscrew something, so I stopped before I damage something. Where do you suggest I pry/tap?

Comment: @Manbatton Make sure there is no set screw on the side of the handle. Grab  two opposing wings of the handle and gently rock each one up and down, one side up as and the other side down while trying pull up gently on the handle as you do it. if that does not work then try the same technique with two small/thin flat blade screwdrivers wedged in the little slot between the handle and the bell. You may try dropping a few drop of penetrating oil in the little hole on top and let it sit overnight first.

Comment: Stretching to find a hidden set screw I wonder . .  . if one of the four arms has a cap in the end which pries off and a set screw is inside that. The hole in the center might be for a pop-in "C" or "H" tag. What does the other handle look like?

Comment: @Alaskaman I tried rocking it to test that and there's not even a suggestion of movement. I didn't go any further because I want to be very conservative on this because I don't really own this sink so I'd rather not "try" things unless someone knows it works with these faucets. Thanks.

Comment: The only other suggestion I could think of is it's threaded on but that's unlikely.  You could turn the water off under the sink and use a little more force than you feel comfortable with or you can call your landlord

Answer (score 1):

To remove the trim - aka faucet handle and rosette, unthread the rosette, which will remove BOTH the rosette and the handle/lever at the same time.
Many Kohler, grohe and price pfister faucets’ handle assemblies install this way.